# What is the meaning of statement below that the declared type shall not be incomplete type

Tags: c, definition, linkage

The C standard states:

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object is a tentative
>   definition and has internal linkage, the declared type shall not be an
>   incomplete type

What does it mean that "the declared type shall not be an incomplete type"?

Answer (score 1):

That means you are not allowed to have:

```
static int arr[]; // This is illegal as per the quoted standard.
int main(void) {}
```

The array `arr`is tentatively defined and has an incomplete type (lacks information about the size of the object) and also has internal linkage (`static` says `arr` has internal linkage).

Whereas the following (at file scope),

```
int i; // i is tentatively defined. Valid.

int arr[]; // tentative definition & incomplete type. A further definition 
           // of arr can appear elsewhere. If not, it's treated like
           //  int arr[] = {0}; i.e. an array with 1 element.
           // Valid.
```

are valid.

Comment: no man compiler is not giving error ..thats what i thought  first

Comment: Do you enforce the strict standard compliance? When I do `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 t.c`, I get `t.c:1:12: error: array size missing in ‘arr’
t.c:1:12: warning: ‘arr’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]`. gcc by default enables many extensions and may not satisfy for all requirements of C standard. With the above options, it'd produce better diagnostics.